# Why always I ma getting connection time out exception in zuul api gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

```
I am using Netflix Zuul and Eureka . There are 3 instances of my client application registered in Eureka and all are up and running.


always I am getting connection time out exception?
Please find below zuul api gateway application.properties and error
spring.application.name=netflix-zuul-api-gateway-server
server.port=8765
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Error:
Fri Mar 22 21:18:23 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
GENERAL
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com:9000 [5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/10.212.226.226, 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/fe80:0:0:0:eded:ff6a:cdf1:fed1%17, 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/fe80:0:0:0:4:352c:f52b:1d1d%14] failed: connect timed out

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com:9000 [5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/10.212.226.226, 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/fe80:0:0:0:eded:ff6a:cdf1:fed1%17, 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com/fe80:0:0:0:4:352c:f52b:1d1d%14] failed: connect timed out
**strong text**

**strong text**

Comment: There's not enough information to begin to help out.

Comment: looks like network problem, can you call API of 5CG7084F28840.corpzone.internalzone.com:9000 ?

Comment: while calling direct api its working fine. but while calling through zuul api gateway I am getting above error